# How to increase the size(width) of the SVG line only

Tags: javascript, svg, line, dimple.js

I have a line and a marker on it. Now I want to increase only the width of the line not the arrow. If I give stroke-width both the size of the line and the markert is increasing.

here is my fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/keshav_1007/pwr7043d/7/

```
var yMax = 1.2;
            var svg1 = dimple.newSvg("body", 370, 230);
             var data = [{
            "Brand":"A", 
            "Day":"Mon", 
            "SalesVolume":10 },
            { 
            "Brand":"B", 
            "Day":"Mon", 
            "SalesVolume":20 }];
            var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg1, data);
            myChart.setBounds(120, 10, 170, 150)

            var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Day");
            var y = myChart.addPctAxis("y", "SalesVolume");
            y.overrideMax = yMax;
            y.addOrderRule("SalesVolume");
            var s = myChart.addSeries("Brand",dimple.plot.bar);
            s.getTooltipText = function (e) {
                var graphValue = (e.aggField[0]);
                return [
                    ""+graphValue+""
                ];
            };
            s.barGap=0.7;
            myChart.draw();

            var defs = svg1.append("defs");
            defs.append("marker")
            .attr("id", "triangle-start")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 10)
            .attr("refY", 5)
            .attr("markerWidth", 10)
            .attr("markerHeight", 10)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "marker")
            .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z");

             svg1.append("line")
            .attr("x1", 140)
            .attr("x2", 195)
             .attr('stroke','black')

            .attr("y1", y._scale(0.5))
            .attr("y2", y._scale(0.5))
            .attr("marker-start", "url(#triangle-start)");
```

please let me know how to increase the size of the line alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the marker size is relative to the stroke-width, if you don't want that then you can use the [`markerUnits`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#MarkerUnitsAttribute) attribute to make the size be relative to the current userspace coordinate system.

So, just add:

```
.attr("markerUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
```

to where the marker element is created, and tweak the size to what you want it to be. After that changing the stroke-width should not affect the size of the marker.